# How to use the mnsymbol package properly

Tags: mnsymbol

Can someone give me any advice on how to use the mnsymbol package properly? When I run the following code it doesn't work. I get the computer modern font.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,DIV=11]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Frutiger LT Std}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sum x + y = \frac{25x - (10-xy)}{den}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which symbol from the `MnSymbol` do you want to use?

Comment: `MnSymbol` only provides symbols, not letters.

Comment: If you load the `MinionPro` package, you will gets all maths letters typed with MinionPro, and it load `Mnsymbol`.  Your typing would be more consistent.

Comment: I only want to use it as a math font. I don't want to use the MinionPro package if possible.

Comment: Do you mean that the summation symbol is CM? The rest you'd expect to be CM anyway, right?